# Does a univariate ARIMA model become mulitvariate when I add exogenous variabels to the function? I did this in r with the function xreg

Tags: r, regression, predict, multivariate-testing, autoregressive-models

Does a univariate ARIMA model become mulitvariate when I add exogenous variabels to the function? I did this in r with the function xreg.

For example: `fitwithtwoexfactors = arima(futoilrtn,order=c(0,0,1), xreg=exogenous)`

exogenous is a data frame with two columns.

Comment: As you analyze two variables at a time, I would say, it is a bivariate and so a multivariate model.

Comment: Thank you! Does this follow for an ARMA model as well. I understand that the I in ARIMA is the back shifter operator, but my time series is already stationary so I believe this is an ARMAX and multivariate if I have multiple exogenous variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ARIMA model does not become a multivariate model. Multivariate models are models with two or more dependent variables. The objective of the exogenous variables is to hopefully make better predictions of the future by minimizing MSE.